# Using Google Webfonts some accented characters appear bold and too big

Tags: google-webfonts

See http://jsfiddle.net/2CJc5/5/

The fiddle just displays this string using a webfont:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gudea';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Gudea Italic'), local('Gudea-Italic'),         url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/gudea/v1/7K8okIOV072GIwnptze9lg.woff)     format('woff');
}

{code}
więcej transakcji za granicą niż w kraju
{code}
```

This looks really bad on my Polish website

Answer (score 0):

There were two different problems:
1. Gudea does not have these special characters at all. The fallback sans-serif was used.
2. I forgot to add the extended latin charset to Titillium